# Is it legal to bind gl_InstanceID as uniform location?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I have a GLSL shader that makes use of the gl_InstanceID input variable which is set by a glDrawArraysInstanced all. I want this shader to work with a drawcall that doesn't set gl_InstanceID. Here, I want to set gl_InstanceID manually uniform style.

Is it legal / defined behavior to bind glInstanceID as a uniform for these cases?

```
GLint const instanceIdx = glGetUniformLocation(pid, "gl_InstanceID");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to manually provide a value for `gl_InstanceID`, getting its location as a uniform isn't going to work for several reasons but mainly because it's *not a uniform*. It is a built-in [vertex shader input variable](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Other_inputs), which is different from a vertex attribute (which is user provided, not built-in).

The value of `gl_InstanceID` will be zero for any draw call that doesn't use instancing. If you want it to be non-zero for such calls, that's not possible. `gl_BaseInstance` from GLSL 4.60/ARB_shader_draw_parameters will track the base instance value from [BaseInstance draw calls](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Instancing). So you could use that to effectively set the instance index.

But without that, there's nothing you can do.